# Netbeans not regognizing project for subversion

Tags: svn, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7 and have subversion client in it. I manage to do subversion checkout and all the other subversion functions are also available, but the project is still not quite regognized for subversion. There are no blue marks on folders, and when I try to run the application I get the error

```
Execute failed:
```

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svnversion" (in directory "C:\Users\Jaana\Documents\NetBeansProjects\tuha"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor98.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)

Any help!!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes find that the bundled Client doesn't work in which case I use one of the external clients that are available, and just point NetBeans at them.